# RxJS5 TypeScript typings fail

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, tsc

I run `tsc` on my project, and I get these errors relating to the RxJS5 lib:

```
$ tsc
node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.d.ts(11,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventTarget'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.d.ts(11,103): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NodeList'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.d.ts(11,114): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLCollection'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(16,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(77,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(82,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(97,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(98,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(108,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(108,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(119,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(128,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.d.ts(136,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(10,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MessageEvent'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(11,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(12,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CloseEvent'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(15,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(27,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(28,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(29,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CloseEvent'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(32,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(36,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MessageEvent'.
```

does anyone know why this is happening? this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "oplog.rx",
  "version": "0.0.101",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "suman test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ORESoftware/oplog.rx.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "oplog",
    "mongodb",
    "rx",
    "rxjs"
  ],
  "author": "Olegzandr V.D.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ORESoftware/oplog.rx/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ORESoftware/oplog.rx#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bson": "^2.0.4",
    "json-stdio": "0.0.1016",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add `"dom"` to the `lib` setting in your `tsconfig.json` file's `compilerOptions`:

```
"lib": ["dom", "es2015"]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `skipLibCheck` `compilerOption` to avoid checking `.d.ts` files within `node_modules`:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3558) for an explanation.

Basically, the `fromEvent` observable factory supports both Node and DOM event sources and TypeScript needs to know about the DOM types.

[This PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3566) should resolve the problem.

Comment: yeah I guess one question is - why doesn't RxJS include "dom" why do I have to? I am going to use the "skipLibCheck" option, seems useful workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
rimraf dist && tsc

node_modules/broadcast-channel/types/broadcast-channel.d.ts:6:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MessageEvent'.

6     "message": MessageEvent;
```

"typescript": "^4.6.4"
"tsc": "^2.0.4",

After add "dom" to the lib setting in your tsconfig.json file's compilerOptions: "lib": ["dom"]

then everything goes ok.